# Endless loop even when loop is good

Tags: java, loops, jframe

```
public class UI extends javax.swing.JFrame{
    public void start(){
        appendResponse(Bot+": Hello, "+Name + "\n");
        appendResponse(Bot + ": You are in a dark room, you have a backpack full of supplies. What will you do?\n");
        if(input.toLowerCase().equals("open backpack")){
            start2();
        }else{
            while(true){
                appendResponse(Bot + ": Sorry invalid input!\n");
                start();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    private void btnSendActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
        You = Name + ": " +txtInput.getText()+"\n";
        input = txtInput.getText();
        txtRespond.append(You);
        txtInput.setText("");
        if(input.equals("hi")){ 
            appendResponse(Bot+": Hello, "+Name + "\n");
            start();
        }else{
            appendResponse(Bot + ": say hi to computer\n");
        }

    }
}
```

Both the methods are in the same class. 
When i typed hi in my textArea the press send
It keeps appending(to my textArea) " Hello, "+Name
": You are in a dark room, you have a backpack full of supplies. What //will you do?"
and when i typed "open backpack" it responded
"say hi to computer" instead of calling the start2() method

Comment: You are calling `start()` recursively, based on the value of `input`, without actually changing the value of `input`. And the loop isn't actually a loop, since you break it.

Comment: Yup careless mistake. i made it neat already@AndyTurner

Comment: second method's else condition ---> add `start()` after `appendResponse(Bot + ": say hi to computer\n");`.

Answer (score 1):

this

```
while(true){
     appendResponse(Bot + ": Sorry invalid input!\n");
     start();
     break;
}
```

the break is useless because you call again the start method...

then in the start method you never ever do read again the input dooing `input = txtInput.getText();` that means input is holding the same value that brough you to the else condition

```
 if(input.toLowerCase().equals("open backpack")){
```

that will loop until you get soon or later an stackoverflow....

Comment: looks like it was a downvote attack, I see other deleted question downvoted without a reason or comment

Answer (score 0):

The loop isn't the issue here. It's not even looping: you could remove the `while (true)` and the break, and you'd still have the same problem.

The issue is that the condition in `start` checks the value of `input`; but you don't actually change the value of `input`, so once it takes the negative branch, it calls `start()` again, checks `input`, takes the negative branch, etc, until you get a `StackOverflowError`.

You need to assign a new value to `input` before you check it, with some possibility of its value changing.

```
public void start(){
  appendResponse(Bot+": Hello, "+Name + "\n");
  appendResponse(Bot + ": You are in a dark room, you have a backpack full of supplies. What will you do?\n");

  input = /* somehow get input from user */;

  if(input.toLowerCase().equals("open backpack")) {
    start2();
  } else {
    appendResponse(Bot + ": Sorry invalid input!\n");
    start();
  }
}
```

But note that a recursive call isn't a good way to do this. A better way would be:

```
while (true) {
  input = /* get input from user */;
  if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("open backpack")) break;

  appendResponse("invalid");
}
start2();
```